# Resolve ambiguousness of a base template class member

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguity, boost-log

I have a hierarchy of classes and every one of them must have a particular base class. Than base class provides ability to post log records and takes in ctor name of a log channel (basically a name of a class which is using log). Lets call this class `Logable`.

To allow my classes to inherit from that `Logable` class several times, I gave it a template parameter and every descendant uses itself as this parameter.

Actually I'm using a boost::log library, but there is very simplified example of said hierarchy with simple `LogableImpl` class, which is replacing boost::log sink.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// macro for logging in a boost::log style
#define LOG_DEBUG this->_loggerObj.logStream("debug")
#define LOG_INFO  this->_loggerObj.logStream("info")
#define LOG_WARN  this->_loggerObj.logStream("warning")
#define LOG_ERROR this->_loggerObj.logStream("error")


class LogableImpl
{
private:
   std::string _channelName;
public:
   LogableImpl(const std::string & channelName): _channelName(channelName) {}

   std::ostream & logStream(const std::string & severetyLevel)
   {
      std::cout << _channelName << " " << severetyLevel;
      return std::cout;
   }
};


template <class Descendant>
class Logable
{
protected:
   Logable(const std::string & channelName): _loggerObj(channelName) {}
   LogableImpl _loggerObj;
};


class Base: private Logable<Base>
{
public:
   Base()
      : Logable<Base>("Base")
   {}

   void someMethod()
   {
      LOG_INFO << "some method is called" << std::endl;
      LOG_ERROR << "an error happened" << std::endl;
   }
};


class Derived: public Base, private Logable<Derived>
{
public:
   Derived()
      : Logable<Derived>("Derived")
   {}

   void someAnotherMethod()
   {
      LOG_INFO << "another method is called" << std::endl;
      LOG_ERROR << "another error is happened" << std::endl;
   }
};


int main()
{
   Base b;
   Derived d;
   b.someMethod();
   d.someMethod();

   return 0;
}
```

Obviously I've got an error from my compilation attempt of this source with MSVC 2008

```
error C2385: ambiguous access of '_loggerObj'
1>        could be the '_loggerObj' in base 'Logable<Base>'
1>        or could be the '_loggerObj' in base 'Logable<Derived>'
1>d:\cpp\visualstudio\tests\workbench\test\main.cpp(55) : error C2248: 'Logable<Descendant>::_loggerObj' : cannot access inaccessible member declared in class 'Logable<Descendant>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Descendant=Base
1>        ]
1>        d:\cpp\visualstudio\tests\workbench\test\main.cpp(29) : see declaration of 'Logable<Descendant>::_loggerObj'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Descendant=Base
1>        ]
1>d:\cpp\visualstudio\tests\workbench\test\main.cpp(56) : error C2385: ambiguous access of '_loggerObj'
1>        could be the '_loggerObj' in base 'Logable<Base>'
1>        or could be the '_loggerObj' in base 'Logable<Derived>'
1>d:\prog\cpp\visualstudio\tests\workbench\boost_test\main.cpp(56) : error C2248: 'Logable<Descendant>::_loggerObj' : cannot access inaccessible member declared in class 'Logable<Descendant>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Descendant=Base
1>        ]
1>        d:\cpp\visualstudio\tests\workbench\test\main.cpp(29) : see declaration of 'Logable<Descendant>::_loggerObj'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Descendant=Base
1>        ]
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\cpp\visualStudio\tests\workbench\test\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>boost_test - 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How can I specify right base member to use in a `LOG_*` macro?
I feel that it can be done with some template magic, but just cant figure it out.

It must be done with MSVC2008, which does not support C++11x features

Comment: Well, which `_loggerObj` do you want to use in the `Derived` case?

Comment: @Barry - That one, that is in the direct `Logable` ancestor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to replace `decltype` to something that msvc 2008 could understand to use Petr's answer. Even `boost::typeof` were not suitable (as long as I used it correctly)

So I came with a solution by adding a `using` case with a macro

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define USE_APPROPRIATE_LOGGER(classname) using Logable<classname>::_loggerObj
#define LOG_DEBUG _loggerObj.logStream("debug")
#define LOG_INFO  _loggerObj.logStream("info")
#define LOG_WARN  _loggerObj.logStream("warning")
#define LOG_ERROR _loggerObj.logStream("error")

class LogableImpl
{
private:
   std::string _channelName;
public:
   LogableImpl(const std::string & channelName): _channelName(channelName) {}

   std::ostream & logStream(const std::string & severetyLevel)
   {
      std::cout << _channelName << " " << severetyLevel << " ";
      return std::cout;
   }
};


template <class Descendant>
class Logable
{
protected:
   Logable(const std::string & channelName): _loggerObj(channelName) {}
   LogableImpl _loggerObj;
};

class Base: private Logable<Base>
{
   USE_APPROPRIATE_LOGGER(Base);
public:
   Base()
      : Logable<Base>("Base")
   {}

   void someMethod()
   {
      LOG_INFO << "some method is called" << std::endl;
      LOG_ERROR << "an error happened" << std::endl;
   }
};

class Derived: public Base, private Logable<Derived>
{
   USE_APPROPRIATE_LOGGER(Derived);
public:
   Derived()
      : Logable<Derived>("Derived")
   {}

   void someAnotherMethod()
   {
      LOG_INFO << "another method is called" << std::endl;
      LOG_ERROR << "another error is happened" << std::endl;
   }
};


int main()
{
   Base b;
   Derived d;
   b.someMethod();
   std::cout << std::endl;
   d.someAnotherMethod();

   return 0;
}
```

Its ugly and kills idea of using inheritance to provide logability to class, but it seems that there is no other way without c++11

Comment: Yes, I have also been thinking of using `using` to work without c++11, just did not find time to make it a running case.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this using c++11 by explicitly specifying which `Logable` should be used. As we do not know the type of `this`, I use `decltype`:

```
#define LOGABLE_TYPE typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type
#define LOG_DEBUG this->Logable<LOGABLE_TYPE>::_loggerObj.logStream("debug")
#define LOG_INFO  this->Logable<LOGABLE_TYPE>::_loggerObj.logStream("info")
#define LOG_WARN  this->Logable<LOGABLE_TYPE>::_loggerObj.logStream("warning")
#define LOG_ERROR this->Logable<LOGABLE_TYPE>::_loggerObj.logStream("error")
```

See full code here: http://ideone.com/1D5jrj

Comment: Thank you for answer. Sorry, I forgot to mention that it must be done with MSVC 2008, which does not support C++11x